# How do I put a switch in line for LED tube lights using 120 volts

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

I have a LED tube light for my basement it will come on if I put 120v to it. How can I put a switch in line?  That is all I have I do not know what a code is.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a _lot_ more information if you expect a decent answer. Are these plug-in lights or are they hard-wired? What kind of "in-line" switch are you expecting to add? Where in the world are you (North America is ass-u-med based on 120v, but a code-compliant answer requires we know for sure. If in NA/USA, a state is helpful because of varying NEC adoption).

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with basic circuit switching you might not be up to the task of doing house wiring in the first place. I suggest finding a good wiring primer and doing some reading. There are ways you can screw this up that are dangerous.

Comment: You need an old fluorescent fixture to mount this tube in.

Fortunately, they're free.  Hit up Craigslist and/or Freecycle and *ask for one*.   People upgrading to LED fixtures find out a 4' fluorescent fixture won't fit in a trash can, so they're *happy* to get rid of em!